# How to write text at the same height of other text, but in the other side?

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to create a header with black background with my name on the left, with "journalist" below it, and some text on the right. But I can't see what's wrong, because when I try this, the other text appears under the level of the two other texts (name and journalist), not at the same height. Help, please?

Sorry for the language, I'm brazilian and begginer in coding.

```css
.fundo-header {
  background-color: #2D2C2F;
  background-position: center;
  height: 14%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.subtitulo {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<header class="fundo-header">
  <div>
    <h1>Pedro Henrique</h1>
    <h4 class="subtitulo">Jornalista</h4>
  </div>
  <h2 style="text-align:right">ramdom text</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

div is a block-level element, which means that it occupies the entire space of it's parent. You can get around this by setting your h2 to float: right;

```
<header class="fundo-header">
    <h2 style="float:right">ramdom text</h2>
    <div>
        <h1>Pedro Henrique</h1>
        <h4 class="subtitulo">Jornalista</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

If you don't need IE10 support, you can also use flexbox:

```
<header class="fundo-header" style="display: flex;">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
        <h1>Pedro Henrique</h1>
        <h4 class="subtitulo">Jornalista</h4>
    </div>
    <h2>ramdom text</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox solution may be better

```
<header class="fundo-header">
    <div>
        <h1>Pedro Henrique</h1>
        <h4 class="subtitulo">Jornalista</h4>
    </div>
    <h1>ramdom text</h1>
</header>

.fundo-header {
        background-color:#2D2C2F;
        background-position: center;
        height:14%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
}

    body{    
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .subtitulo {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-style: italic;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`h1`, `h2` and `h4` are block elements and therefore use the full with of their parent element by default. That is why the `h2` goes to the next line.

Below I used a flexbox for the parent element and arranged alignment via CSS. Documentation is in the code. Hope this helps.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1,
h2,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
} /* Reset */

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.fundo-header {
  background-color: #2D2C2F;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Horizontal alignment */
  align-items: flex-start; /* Vertical alignment */
  padding: 5%;
}

.subtitulo {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<header class="fundo-header">
  <div>
    <h1>Pedro Henrique</h1>
    <h4 class="subtitulo">Jornalista</h4>
  </div>
  <h2>ramdom text</h2>
</header>
```